# If else statement on join query

Tags: join, postgresql-9.3, condition

i am working with a Postgresql database

having two tables:
professionals[professional_id,user_id,account_id]

users[user_id email]

accounts[account_id email]

professionals

```
 [professional_id,user_id,account_id]

    1,          2000,       null
    2,          3000,        120
    3,          4000,        155
```

users

```
   [user_id,   email]
    2000,   mike@gmail.com
    3000,   joe@gmail.com
    4000,   jack@gmail.com
```

accounts

```
   [account_id ,    email]
   120,          maria@gmail.com
   155,         travis@gmail.com
```

Here i have to get the `email` with doing  a join between `accounts` and `professionals`.

If `account_id is not null` we get the `email`

If the `account_id is null` we do the join between the `users` and `professionals` (we are sure that user_id is always not null)

Here is what i did :

```
select email from professionals  
IF (u.id=m.user2ID)
left JOIN accounts ON accounts.account_id = professionals.account_id
ELSE
LEFT JOIN users  ON users.user_id = professionals.user_id;
```

Thanks indeed for any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*UNTESTED - You did not provide any DDL or sample data scripts...*
IF is a flow control construct that determines which statement block will be executed.
What you need are [Conditional Expressions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-conditional.html). In your case, the `COALESCE` function should do the trick, also look at `CASE` for non null condition predicates.

```
SELECT COALESCE(accounts.email, professionals.email) AS Email 
FROM professionals  
LEFT JOIN accounts ON accounts.account_id = professionals.account_id
LEFT JOIN users  ON users.user_id = professionals.user_id;
```

Comment: thanks @SQLRaptor it is working perfectly , the error that i was getting  the email (because we have `email` from users and accounts) but the `COALESCE `  worked to solve the problem :-)

Comment: could you please explain what do you mean by `also look at CASE for non null condition predicates.` thanks

Comment: Just look in the link I mentioned, it explains CASE - https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-conditional.html. COALESCE is a conditional expression for NULL predicates - it returns the first non null expression. 
CASE is a more general purpose tool, and is extremely useful in other cases. Since you were not familiar with conditional expressions, I just thought it is something worth mentioning. You could replace the COALESCE with something like "... CASE WHEN accounts.email IS NULL THEN professionals.email ELSE accounts.email END AS Email ... "